# Is it possible to use iframe without linking another page

Tags: html, iframe

This is classic iframe code. All I want is to show different things when you click different links.

I want to display different galleries in wordpress on a page with different links. I don't wanna code different html's for each of them

```
<iframe id="myIframe" src="about:blank" height="200" width="500"></iframe>
<br />
<a href="http://www.blogger.com" target="myIframe">Blogger</a><br />
<a href="http://www.cnn.com" target="myIframe">CNN</a><br />
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="myIframe">Google</a><br />
```

Comment: If you just want to display the word blogger I don't see a justification of using an `iframe` in the first place

Comment: I want to display different galleries in wordpress on a page with different links. I don't wanna code different html's for each of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do is show and hide specific parts of the page when clicking on a link. You don't need to use iframes for that. I think you'd better use hidden div's for this, or maybe even an ajax call to load the different galleries. I'll show you the hidden divs approach :

```
<div id="gallery1" class="gallery">
  A whole lot of html that makes up the 1st gallery
</div>
<div id="gallery2" class="gallery" style="display:none">
  A whole lot of html that makes up the 2nd gallery
</div>
<div id="gallery3" class="gallery" style="display:none">
  A whole lot of html that makes up the 3nd gallery
</div>

<a href="JavaScript:void(0)" data-gallery="gallery1">Show gallery 1</a>
<a href="JavaScript:void(0)" data-gallery="gallery2">Show gallery 2</a>
<a href="JavaScript:void(0)" data-gallery="gallery3">Show gallery 3</a>

​
$('a').click(function() {
  $('.gallery').hide();
  $('#' + $(this).data('gallery')).show();
});
```

Here's a js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nV5vy/

Comment: I want to display different galleries in wordpress on a page with different links. I don't wanna code different html's for each of them.

Comment: Ah I understand the question now, Let me see

Comment: I changed the solution, nut I'm sill not sure what you're trying to do. What is it exactly that you want to display in the iframe? The content of the URLs. the word of the link you clicked, or something else?

Comment: Thank you for the help ! is there any chance I can put any text besides blogger ? lets say I want people to see blogger logo in iframe when they click blogger... Can I do that ?

Comment: goo.gl/QOmlI -> This is the page I`m working on. I want people to see different galleries when they click each link on left hand side. I figured I can make it work with iframes

Comment: So if I understand correctly you want to show a different blob of HTML (the different galeries) when users click a link? In that case I would not use iframes, but hidden divs. Shall I create an example for you?

Comment: yes please. I think jquery would be good but I dont know how could I change their display none to block with a click event